# Random order of two different result types?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two types of ads. Paid and free. When a zip code is queried all the matching ads are returned along with a designation of free or paid. I want to show the paid ads first, then the free ads next. This is simple enough, but is there a way to randomize the display order for each type separately? A single random sort would place some free ads before some paid ones.

Comment: Your question seems a bit contradictory. "paid ads first" but "some free ads before some paid ones"? Oh, nevermind, you were pointing out what wouldn't work.

Comment: If there's a boolean/numeric flag in the table already, like `paid`, then just ORDER BY that firstly, and RAND() secondly.

Comment: I want to have the paid ads display randomly first, then the free ads displayed randomly after that.

Comment: Is this question about **weighting** results with an element of randomness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most generic form of the kind of query you need:

```
SELECT *
FROM the_table
ORDER BY [some_type_field(s)], RAND()
;
```